# How to change custom post type permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have 2 Custom Post Type : `article` and `multipager_article`

Now I want to customize permalink structure for these 2 custom post type only

I want Structure like this :

```
site_url/term_slug/post_id
```

I tried different hooks , but no luck
It works for 1 post type , and breaking other post type

```
 function post_type_permalink( $post_link, $post) {
  if( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'article' ){
     $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'language' );
     $parameters = ['%article_tax%','%post_id%'];
     $values = [$terms[0]->slug, $post->ID];
     $post_link = str_replace($parameters,$values,$post_link);
  }
  return $post_link;
 }
 add_filter('post_link', 'post_type_permalink', 1, 3);
 add_filter('post_type_link', 'post_type_permalink', 1, 3);
```

I have set rewrite slug on the article post type,

```
class Article extends PostTypeAbstract{
/**
 * @return array<string, mixed>
 */
public function getOptions(): array
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%article_tax%','(.+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%post_id%','(.+)');

    return [
        'label'        => $this->getName(),
        'description'  => $this->getDescription(),
        'public'       => true,
        'show_ui'      => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php',
        'supports'     => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'],
        'rewrite'   => array('slug' => '%article_tax%/%post_id%', 'with_front' => false)
    ];
}}
```

Above code, I have tried but it works for only `article` post type, if I set rewrite for the `mutlipager_article` so it is going to the 404 page.

any help would be appreciated